# Isosceles Triangle/Circle

Tags: derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

what are the dimensions of the isosceles triangle with minimum area that can contain the circle inside it.

Do your results match the max from a "Brute-force" method? That means you just plug in many possible base and height lengths, do the area calculation for each, and finding the min. (excel recommended)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMQsk.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZx7A.jpg)

This is what I got I do not have any other information to give, I think need to find the radius first and use the derivative to find the critical points and after that minimum points that is what I think. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Shaun How do you generate auto comment like this, thanks!

Comment: I copy & paste them from the meta site, @KingTut; you can find some [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4928#4928).

Comment: @Shaun Oh nice thanks!

Comment: May be an audit

Comment: Using calculus is too complicated.  Consider using inequalities: fix the radius $r$ of the inradius first, then use Heron's formula to fix $\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)/s}$.  I think some AM-GM arguemt will work.